# shinydashboard: filtering DT by textInput

Tags: r, filter, shiny, reactive-programming, shinydashboard

I want to build a pretty straightforward functionality where a user chooses a file to process and then different outputs based on the **full** content of the file are shown in various data.tables across multiple menu tabs. Additionally, I want a user to be able to filter **all those data.tables** by value present in all the output that would be taken from `textInput` field. So, it should follow the logic: if the `textInput` is empty, then show all the records otherwise show only those records that match the value from `textInput`. Easy, right?

Here's a dummy example:

```
### ui.R

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

dbSidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
textInput(inputId = "search_term",
          label = "Search"),

# one of many tabs
menuItem("General Info", tabName = "general_info", icon = icon("info-sign", lib = "glyphicon")),

downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download',
               icon("paper-plane"), 
               style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4;
               margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 15px;")
    )
  )

general_info_tab <- tabItem(tabName = "general_info",
                           fluidRow(
                             box(h2("Companies House Search Data"),
                                 DT::dataTableOutput('searchTable')
                                 ),
                             width = 12)
                           )

dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dbSidebar,
  dashboardBody(
tabItems(
  general_info_tab
    )
  )
)


### server.R

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

# my hypothetical file content
dummy_data <- data.frame(
  a = rep(c(1,2,3), 6),
  b = rep(c("A2746", "38504", "CD759")),
  fruit = rep(c("apple", "pear"), each = 9)
)



shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$searchTable = DT::renderDataTable({

    selected <- dummy_data

if(!is.null(input$search_term) ||
   !is.na(input$search_term) ||
   length(input$search_term) > 0 ||
   input$search_term != "") {

  selected <- filter(dummy_data, b == input$search_term)

}

DT::datatable(selected)

  })
})
```

With this code I see empty dataset **unless** I have `textInput` values. How can I make it appear as a full dataset by default (when `textInput` field empty) and filter it down when I write text? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column **b** is stored as **factors** i think and the filter method is not working correctly.

The following example transforms the column b to character and it uses **partial matching** for the b column.

I used the `tidyselect` package for the partial filtering, although you could also do it with `dplyr` only. Then you should exchange the filter with this one:
`filter(dummy_data, grepl(input$search_term, b))`.

```
library(tidyselect)

dummy_data$b <- as.character(dummy_data$b)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$searchTable = DT::renderDataTable({
    selected <- dummy_data
    if (input$search_term != "") {
      selected <- filter(dummy_data, b == vars_select(dummy_data$b, contains(input$search_term)))
    }
    DT::datatable(selected)
  })

})
```

Comment: BTW, if you want to stick to `tidyverse`, you can use `stringr` package to get a similar result by applying the following filter: `filter(str_detect(b, input$search_term))`